# How show tag <option> in <datalist> even input do not match?

Tags: html

I have an `input` field where I connected `datalist`.

How I can show all 'option' tags in 'datalist' even input do not match the text entered.

```html
<input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="sample, map" list="listRows" />
<datalist id="listRows">
  <option value="aye">Aye</option>
  <option value="eh">Eh</option>
</datalist>
```

For example, how show 2 options if I input random text?

Comment: You have tagged this with javascript, but have not provided any javascript code. You should either remove the tag or post the code you think is involved.

Comment: I have an inflatable boat. It is made for use in the water. How can I make this boat fly in the air? For ex, I jump out of plane and water is not close - how I use boat to survive?

Comment: You may use a `<select>` element instead

Comment: You cannot. Datalist is not supposed to have something like multiple `selected` or always `display:block` `<option>`s. You should go for some custom JS+HTML solution.

Comment: @enxaneta me need search bar solution, and <select> not exactly what I need. Datalist and input The perfect solution for me.